# Remove wrapping around ListBox item

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following code:

```
<!-- Accounts list -->
<ListBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AccountViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Style="{StaticResource AccountsList}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <LocalViews:AccountView Margin="{StaticResource ControlMargin}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Which renders as:

[image]

How do I:

1. Remove the highlight around the selected item
2. (and/or) remove the extra top and bottom margin it creates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As bad as it sounds, answering my own question, here is the solution

```
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This removes the extra styling around `ListBoxItem` and makes it look as if it were an `ItemsControl`, which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: In my opinion it does not sound bad to answer your own question here. Actually you may be helping some users by sharing your solution. For example, your solution perfectly resolved the same issue I had had (my one upvote). Thank you for sharing your solution, and you may want to mark it as an `Answer` as well since readers pay more attention to a `response` that is marked as an `Answer`; otherwise, some may think the issue is still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use `ItemsControl` instead of `ListBox`. It doesn't have the concept of selection.

However if you want full control over the presentation and layout of the control, you'll need to set your own control templates for the control and its sub elements. Examples are available on MSDN, or you can use a tool to extract the templates from an existing class and make your own modifications.

Comment: Exactly, I was using `ItemsControl` before I switched to `ListBox` for its selection properties. I think I might be reversing back to it ...

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the ListBox in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose Edit Additional Templates->Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)->Edit a Copy to copy the default control template for the ListBoxItem into your XAML markup and then edit it as per your requirements by removing some MultiTriggers:

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AccountViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Style="{StaticResource AccountsList}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <!--<MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>-->
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <LocalViews:AccountView Margin="{StaticResource ControlMargin}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Padding around every item, you can overwrite the `Padding` property in the ListBoxItem Style.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

In contrast to your approach (setting `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`) this won't generate the blue selection, but keep the standard selection of an default ListBox.